# Dropdowns using select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a dropdown menu with some categories. Whenever i click a cetain category, i want it to expand and show the respective subcategories (like dropdowns inside other dropdowns).

I'm using `select2`, and i would also like it to have a search option, so the final look is someting like this:

[image]

Here's a fiddle with what i have so far:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcarou/S8CUa/185/)

And the code:

```
<label for="id_label_multiple">
  Click this to highlight the multiple select element
  <select class="js-example-basic-single  js-states form-control" id="id_label_multiple">
    <optgroup label="fruits1">
      <option>Apple1</option>
      <option>Apple2</option>
      <option>Apple3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="fruits2">
      <option>Apple4</option>
      <option>Apple5</option>
      <option>Apple6</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="fruits3">
      <option>Apple7</option>
      <option>Apple8</option>
      <option>Apple9</option>
    </optgroup>
   </select>
</label>

 <script>
     $('#id_label_multiple').select2();
</script>
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: i've edited my question @palaѕн

Comment: It seems like you didn't add select2 to your fiddle.  Also, bootstrap requires a jquery version of 1.9.1 or higher.

Comment: i've updated the fiddle already @Anthony

Comment: it doens't work... your tip didin't change anything. My main concern are the dropdowns inside other dropdowns, how can i do that? @Anthony

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible with select2 but you can manipulate lists to get the effect you want. You can follow [this post](http://www.htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns/).